# Reading pixel bytes from CFData: Arithmetic on a pointer to incomplete type

Tags: ios, objective-c, compiler-errors, core-foundation, bytebuffer

This code should get me each pixel's values starting from a `CGImageRef`:

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mask.bmp"];
CGImageRef aCGImageRef = image.CGImage;

CFDataRef rawData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(aCGImageRef));
UInt8 * buf = (UInt8 *) CFDataGetBytePtr(rawData);
int length = CFDataGetLength(rawData);

CFRelease(rawData);

int no_of_channels = 3;
int image_width = SCREEN_WIDTH();

unsigned long row_stride = image_width * no_of_channels; // 960 bytes in this case
unsigned long x_offset = x * no_of_channels;

/* assuming RGB byte order (as opposed to BGR) */
UInt8 r = *(rawData + row_stride * y + x_offset );
UInt8 g = *(rawData + row_stride * y + x_offset + 1);
UInt8 b = *(rawData + row_stride * y + x_offset + 2);
```

These last three lines would do the trick, but the compiler says it won't do it with `x` and `y` as `float`s. So I casted them to `int`, but now it says

> Arithmetic on a pointer to an incomplete type const struct __CFData

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 3):

You want to do your arithmetic on the byte pointer itself, not to the `CFData` struct (which has the bytes as a member). That means using the `buf` variable from above:

```
UInt8 r = *(buf + row_stride * y + x_offset );
UInt8 g = *(buf + row_stride * y + x_offset + 1);
UInt8 b = *(buf + row_stride * y + x_offset + 2);
```

Comment: +1 but I'll also note: OP should not `CFRelease(rawData)` before accessing the bytes. There's no guarantee that `buf` is still a valid pointer after that.

Comment: In other words: @RickON, remember that `rawData` in your code refers to the CFData object, not the raw data *in* that object. `buf` (the data object's bytes pointer) is the pointer to the actual raw data.

Comment: Hey guys! Thanks for the support! It's being great! That is weird... your suggestion passed.. but the final results were not what I was expecting. I tried two Bitmap images (8bit and 24bit). They both have only black and white pixels. But the r, g and b keep telling me these pixels are any other color. I think that the "no_of_channels" should be 3, as I am not working with the alpha channel, right? Any ideas?

Comment: Just so you know: Now I loaded the image at my init() class (never using "CFRelease(rawData)". While the user is moving sprites around its callback function is called to check the pixels. This way I don't have to load the image all over again.

Comment: That's probably a good subject for another question, @RickON.

Comment: I'll make it so Josh! Tks!

Comment: We can follow from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20959504/getting-unexpected-pixels-from-raw-image